# D3_Redraw chart with filter

Tags: html, d3.js, checkbox, filter, listener

I have viz with three checkboxes working as filters and displayed circles according to the group (see picture below)
[image: viz with checkboxes]

In my work I use `draw` function to visualize all data. Problem is when I click on any checkbox, viz disappears and don't redraw. Can you help to find error here?

Snippet of my html-file:

```
<body>
<div class="centered" style="padding-top: 25px">
</div>
<div id="svganchor" class="graph centered">
</div>
<div id="checkboxes" class="centered">
    <span style="position:relative; top: 3px">Toggle Elements:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="jump" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Jumps
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="jumpColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #1976D2;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="spin" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Spins
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="spinColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #388E3C;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="seq" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Sequences
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="seqColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #D81B60;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</style>
</div>
</body>
```

Snippet of my js-file:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", filter);
    function filter() {

        function getCheckedBoxes(checkboxName) {

            let checkboxes = d3.selectAll(checkboxName).nodes();
            let checkboxesChecked = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].defaultValue);
                }
            }
            return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
        }

        let checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes(".element");

        let newData = [];

        if (checkedBoxes == null) {
            dataSet = newData;
            draw();
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++){
            let newArray = data.filter(function(d) {
                return d.element === checkedBoxes[i];
            });
            Array.prototype.push.apply(newData, newArray);
        }

        dataSet = newData;
        draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to input values:

```html
   <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Jumps" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Jumps
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="jumpColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #1976D2;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Spins" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Spins
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="spinColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #388E3C;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Sequences" class="mdl-checkbox__input element" checked="">Sequences
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label" id="seqColor" style="font-size: 20px; color: #D81B60;">&#9679;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain your answer in more detail. People (usually) come here to learn, not just to get a copy/paste answer. Thanks.